# Probability of $\det M = 0$ where $M$ is a matrix with random $-1, 1$ entries

Tags: probability

Let $M$ be a $n \times n$ matrix with entries taken randomly and independently with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ amongst $\{-1, 1\}$. 
Prove that $Pr(\det M = 0) \geq (1 - \mathcal{o(1)})n^2\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$.

I know that $$Pr(\det M = 0) \geq Pr(\text{M has at least two equal columns}) = 1 - Pr(\text{M has distinct columns}) = 1 - \frac{{{2^n}\choose{n}} \cdot n!}{(2^n)^n}$$
but I cannot carry on.

In the corrected version, they say $Pr(\text{M has distinct columns}) = \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(1 - \frac{i}{2^n})$ and then proceed to find a bound using exponential and Taylor expansion. The equality seems true after comparing it with what I have, but I cannot understand how they can find it straight away.

Also, would there be a nicer, clever way of solving this problem ?